# How to start my model using convolutional neural network

Tags: python, conv-neural-network

i am new to programming, python and all. i am tasked with a work at school that requires me to develop and evaluate abusive language detection models from a given dataset. my proposed model must be a Convolutional Neural Network with an appropriate embedding layer as a first layer. my problem is i don't know how to start as i am very new to this with no prior knowledge

Comment: The Question is really open-ended, but I would recommend that you read any introductory python tutorial(official website, w3school, etc) till the level that you are confident understanding variables, loops, if conditions and how to include/use packages. 
Then move on to Keras [https://keras.io/],  it's the easiest way to get a model up and running, I assume you at least have the theoretical  machine learning knowledge from your course

Answer (score 0):

First, you can start reading and have understanding of a CNN first. 
https://towardsdatascience.com/a-comprehensive-guide-to-convolutional-neural-networks-the-eli5-way-3bd2b1164a53

Lastly, you can check few sample implementation here

**Keras**:
https://towardsdatascience.com/building-a-convolutional-neural-network-cnn-in-keras-329fbbadc5f5

**Pytorch**:
https://adventuresinmachinelearning.com/convolutional-neural-networks-tutorial-in-pytorch/

**Tensorflow**
https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/cnn